# Pass an array and further arguments into a function. How?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function which takes an array and further arguments like this:
function **arrayandmore([1, 2, 3], 2, 3)**
I need to return the array ([1, 2, 3]) without those elements which equals the arguments coming behind the array. So in this case, the returned array would be:
([1]).

One of my approaches is:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  var i = 0;
  while (i < args.length) {
    var result = args[0].filter(word => word !== args[i]);
    i++;
  }
  console.log(result);
}

destroyer([1, 1, 3, 4], 1, 3);
```

Console returns:

```
[ 1, 1, 4 ]
```

**I don't understand, why it returns one too - I don't understand, why it does not work.**

It is the same with using splice.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  var quant = args.length - 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= quant; i++) {
    if (arr.indexOf(args[i]) !== -1) {
      arr = arr.splice(arr.indexOf(args[i]));
    }
    console.log(arr);
  }
}
destroyer([1, 1, 3, 4], 1, 3);
```

I think, both ways should work. But I don't figure out why they don't.

Comment: so return the array excluding all the elements appearing in the arguments of the function?

Comment: Use the rest operator. `destroyer(arr, ...rest)`. Then you have two arrays which you can filter through.

Comment: Something like this? `const diff = (a, ...b) => a.filter(v => !b.includes(v));`

Comment: what should be the output of `destroyer([1,1], 1)`? Does an element need to appear twice to remove 2 elements from the list?

Comment: Yoshi gave a better solution, but if you want to know why yours doesn't work, you restart the value of `result` on every iteration.  You could start it before the loop (`result = arr[0]`) and then update it in the loop, (`result= result.filter(...)`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` won't work because `result` is being overwritten in every loop. So, it only ever removes the last parameter to the `destroyer` function

You can use the [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to separate the array and the items to be removed.

Then use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like this:

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...toRemove) {
  return arr.filter(a => !toRemove.includes(a))
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 1, 3, 4, 5], 1, 3))
```

Comment: fyi, the `...` you're using is the rest operator, not the spread operator. the rest operator collects all elements into an array, whereas the spread operator allows iterables to be expanded into single arguments/elements.